# Graphical problems with 13.10 / GNOME on MacBook Pro 9.1 (13'', Mid 2012)

Tags: gnome, 13.10, intel-graphics, gnome-terminal, macbook-pro

I have a fresh Saucy installation on my MacBook Pro with a 'little' problem: When I open gnome-terminal, I only see the borders of the window but no window content. Purging the package gnome-terminal and re-installing it had no effect. I'm able to get terminal access via xterm. Here is was lspci listed under VGA:

```
    VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen (rev 09)
    ...
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

For me that looks correct (?) since OSX also listed Intel HD Graphics as graphics card in use. When starting a unity session I have similar graphical problems with gnome-terminal.

When I launch gnome-terminal from xterm there were no observable error outputs..

Does anybody have an idea or a hint how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't exactly conclude which package resolved my problem, but installing KDE beside GNOME solved the problem for me.

I assume that the packages gtk2-engine-oxygen, gtk3-engine-oxygen or a related package did the trick. I installed these to make Firefox look a bit nicer when running on KDE.